# Named, arbitrary size tuple in C++

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, policy-based-design

I am creating a library to draw samples from a bayesian model, as a backend for an R package. Thing is, [MCMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) algorithms tend to give a difficult time debugging. Moreover, [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/) [does not have an easy way to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21229530/1155548); in practice I ended up with a massive amount of "cout" statements.

The issue is when I tried to move everything to a standalone library, I realized I fell in love with Rcpp's [List](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/unofficial-rcpp-api-documentation/#vmld). Is a really neat way to store samples with different dimensions. I tried to understand Rcpp's implementation but sincerely  [I could not comprehend it](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/include/Rcpp) (which is based on [policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)) to try to replicate it.

The question: **Is there any way to implement an arbitrary sized, named tuple?** (in a broad sense, not necessary using C++ tuples).

I know I could link Rcpp using the R install path, but I'm not sure if this could be a good practice or if I will have problems trying to upload the R package to [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) (they are very strict) or using it as a standalone library for users not having R.

Thanks!

Comment: use `boost::any`? [examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any/s02.html)

Comment: Oh, looks promising. But I kind of need the "named" part (question edited). Maybe adding a lookup table to a custom object and overloading the "[" operator could do the trick, but I don't know in advance (I learned C a long time ago, but I am new to C++ in general). What do you think?

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::any>`?

Comment: You can do whatever pleases inside C++, but recall that when you want to come back to R, you _must_ pass via the `SEXP .Call(....)` interface. Rcpp helps and maps a lot of what _can be mapped_ but for other things _you_ may have to write the mapper.

Comment: That seems reasonable. I don't know if CRAN supports compiling code with C++17 (for the `std::any`)`, but I suppose I could replace it with `boost::any`. Thanks!

Comment: That is documented, and generally "no". C++14 is possible but a stretch. So stick with `boost::any` for the time being.

Comment: In addition to `boost::any`, you can also use `boost::variant` (e.g., `boost::variant<int, string>`) or the recursive variant if you need a nested structure.  But it sounds like you are looking for something simpler like `vector< map<string, int> >`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes! I will wrap up everything with Rcpp + RcppArmadillo to ease the integration with R.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want. If you want to build a list with arbitrary size in Rcpp and return to R side, you can try something like below:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;

std::vector<SEXP> elements;

// do something with the elements and names

Rcpp::List result(elements.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i) {
    result[i] = elements[i];
}

result.attr("names") = Rcpp::wrap(names);
// result can be return to R as a list
```