# Error while using R through the command line

Tags: c++, r, debugging, gcc, gdb

I am working on `mirtCAT` package in R. I need to debug inside a function in this package called `mirtCAT()`. There are many function inside this one which are written in c++. I need to see which function is taking which value. That is why I need to debug inside the c++  functions which I am trying to do using gdb. I am referring this document for the same:

[http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#src-debugging](http:////http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#src-debugging)

When I am using the command `R --debugger=gdb` to start R on the command prompt

It is starting R but I think it is not starting the gcc compiler.

It is throwing the warning :

> unknown option '--debugger=gdb'

I have changed my environment path variables for gcc compiler.

Any suggestions anyone have?

P.S. I also referred to this thread: [Debugging (line by line) of Rcpp-generated DLL under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345537/debugging-line-by-line-of-rcpp-generated-dll-under-windows)

Where @Dirk suggests to start R by using command  `R -d gdb`

which is also not working it says::

```
unknown option '-d'

ARGUEMENT 'gdb' is _ignored_
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you used a space character after `R` in your command `R --debugger=gdb`?

Comment: Isn't it duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/37816260/72178 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
gdb Rgui.exe
(gdb) break WinMain
```

Comment: This answer only applies to one OS.