# R doesn't recognize command line option. (WARNING: unknown option '-d')

Tags: r, windows, gdb

I am trying to use gdb to debug compiled code in an R package in the same way as specified in the video: https://vimeo.com/11937905 and [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.pdf) section 4.4.

These sources say to use the command 
`R -d gdb` when starting R. However, whenever I try to do this I get a message saying `WARNING: unknown option '-d'` and R is started under normal conditions. 
Why isn't R recognizing the -d flag? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: what are the results of `R --help` ?

Comment: Usage: R [command args]

where 'command args' can be

  --arch n   for n=i386, x64, 32 or 64
  any other arguments listed by R --arch x64 --help

Comment: Then the next question is what is the output of `R --arch x64 --help`?

Comment: `R --version` ? have you looked at http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/gdb.shtml ?

Comment: Using pastebin because of length http://pastebin.com/1GNnsRes

Comment: R version info: R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: And yes I was just beginning to read that actually

Comment: Looks like the `-d` option is handled by a wrapper shell script that may not be present on Windows. But what it does isn't very complicated: `echo "*** Further command line arguments ('${args}') disregarded"; echo "*** (maybe use 'run ${args}' from *inside* ${debugger})"; exec ${debugger} ${debugger_args} "${R_binary}"`

Comment: So after looking into this it seems that in order to debug compiled C\C++ code in an R package **on Windows**, you need to have a custom build of R.

Comment: More information for those who want it at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html section 8.4

Answer (score 2):

As @MatthewLueder has found out himself finally **debugging on Windows does not work as on Linux**.

A how-to is described in the [R for Windows FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-debug-code-that-I-have-compiled-and-dyn_002eload_002ded_003f)

The main reason for the missing `-d` argument in `R` seems to be that  **Windows cannot send a signal to a process to interrupt the execution and pass the control to the (`gdb`) debugger**:

- Without interrupting R you cannot set a breakpoint.
- Without starting R into the R console you cannot load libraries to be debugged (without making your hands dirty).

Therefore R on Windows offers a work-around using `RGui` instead of `R`:

```
gdb /path/to/R-3.x.x/bin/x64/Rgui.exe
(gdb) run
```

After starting the `RGui` you are in an R shell and can load your packages
that contain the DLLs to be debugged.

To set breakpoints for debugging you can interrupt R to *break into the debugger* via a menu item that is only visible if `RGui` was started with `gdb`:

[image]

Now you can set breakpoints in your code via `b a_function_name`, enter `c` to continue R, call the function in R and voilà: `gdb` shows the breakpoint hit and
you can debug (stepping through the code and printing variable values).

PS: I am currently developing an R package to improve the debugging of C++ code in R packages since it is quite difficult to view the current values of R variables or `Rcpp` data types in `gdb`: https://github.com/aryoda/R_CppDebugHelper

Comment: wow that's a wonderful package initiative thanks and keep it up