# How to debug (line-by-line) Rcpp generated code in Windows?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to debug `Rcpp` compiled code at run-time. I have been trying to get this to work unsuccessfully, for a very long time.
A very similar question was asked here:  [Debugging (line by line) of Rcpp-generated DLL under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345537/debugging-line-by-line-of-rcpp-generated-dll-under-windows) which asks the same question, but both the question and the answer are far beyond my understanding.

Here is what I have:

```
Windows 7 Pro SP1
R 3.5
Rstudio 1.1.463 with Rcpp.
Rbuild Tools from Rstudio. (c++ compiler)
```

Procedure:
In Rstudio File->New File->C++ File (creates a sample file with a timesTwo function.)

I added a new function in this file:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo2(NumericVector x) {
  for(int ii = 0; ii <= x.size(); ii++)
  {
    x.at(ii) = x.at(ii) * 2;
  }
  return x;
}
```

I checked Source on Save and saved the file as RcppTest.cpp which sources or complies the file successfully.

Run code in Rstudio:

```
data = c(1:10)
data
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
timesTwo2(data)
Error in timesTwo2(data) : Index out of bounds: [index=10; extent=10].
```

The error is because in the for loop is `<= x.size()` so the result is a run-time error.

The question is how can get a debug output about this error that reasonably tells me what happened?
At the very least I would like to know the line in the code that triggered the exception and with which parameters.
Furthermore, I would really like to execute the code line-by-line to just before the exception so I can monitor exactly what is happening.

I can install any additional programs or apply any other settings as long as I can find precise details on how to do it. For now I am starting from scratch just to get it working.  Thank you.

**Update:**
I found this site: [Debugging Rcpp c++ code using gdb](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200655937-Debugging-Rcpp-c-code-using-gdb)
I installed the latest `gcc` 8.1 with `gdb`

I found the `CXXFLAGS` in the `makeconf` file located in `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\etc\x64`
Then I started the `Rgui` as suggested, but when I try `Rcpp:::sourceCpp` I get an error:

```
> library(Rcpp)
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('Rcpptest.cpp')
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:230: warning: overriding recipe for target '.m.o'
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:223: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.m.o'
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/Michael/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64"        -ggdb -O0 -Wall -gdwarf-2 -mtune=generic -c Rcpptest.cpp -o Rcpptest.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -IC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include -DNDEBUG -IC:/Users/Michael/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64 -ggdb -O0 -Wall -gdwarf-2 -mtune=generic -c Rcpptest.cpp -o Rcpptest.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: Rcpptest.o] Error 2
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("Rcpptest.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools:

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
```

It looks like it is loading the new `CXXFLAGS` and it is using `DEBUG`, but it seems that it still cannot compile. Anybody know why from the error?

I tried running Rstudio the same way as `Rgui` and it started with many threads showing in the `gdb` window, but everything in Rstudio ran exactly as before with no additional debug information from Rstudio or `gdb`.

**Update 2:**
As the error above states that `Rgui` did not have Rtools for compiling so I installed the Rtools from the provide link. It installed in C:\Rtools while Rstudio installed in C:\RBuildTools. So I now have 3 compilers, Rtools, RbuildTools and `gcc` with `gdb`.
It compiles now, but still gives the same error as I did in Rstudio. I would like to at least get better error output, like the line and value passed.
The instruction say `Rgui` should have a spot for a break-point, but I cannot find  such an option.

**Update 3**
I was finally able to set up and run a Linux install (Ubuntu 16.04.05).
First here are my `CXXFLAGS`:

```
$ R CMD config CXXFLAGS
-g -O0 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g
```

I had to create a `.R` folder in my home directory and a `Makevar` file in it with just the line

`CXXFLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall -pedantic -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`

This alone took hours as nowhere did it actually say make the folder and file.

Then I executed the commands as Ralf posted, at the break point:

```
> timesTwo2(d1)

Thread 1 "R" hit Breakpoint 1, timesTwo2 (x=...) at RcppTest.cpp:19
19  NumericVector timesTwo2(NumericVector x) {
(gdb) n
20    for (int ii = 0; ii <= x.size(); ii++)
(gdb) n
22      x.at(ii) = x.at(ii) * 2;
(gdb) display ii
1: ii = 0
(gdb) n
20    for (int ii = 0; ii <= x.size(); ii++)
1: ii = 0
(gdb) n
22      x.at(ii) = x.at(ii) * 2;
1: ii = 1
(gdb) n
20    for (int ii = 0; ii <= x.size(); ii++)
1: ii = 1
(gdb) display x.at(ii)
2: x.at(ii) = <error: Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.>
(gdb) n
22      x.at(ii) = x.at(ii) * 2;
1: ii = 2
2: x.at(ii) = <error: Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.>
(gdb)
```

And finally at `n = 10`:

```
1: ii = 10
2: x.at(ii) = <error: Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.>
(gdb) n
0x00007ffff792d762 in Rf_applyClosure () from /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so
(gdb)
```

This is definitely the furthest I have come to debugging, but this is a very basic function and the debug output and even the error output was not very useful. It gave me the line it was executing and it could display ii, but I could not display the array value or the entire array. Is it possible to create a more specific break point such that it only breaks when `ii == 10`?
Ideally I would like this in Rstudio or some other GUI that can display the entire vector. Still doing more testing.

Comment: See _Writing R Extensions_ on invoking a debugger.  Far from ideal but we have, apart from good old `print` statements.

Comment: my cpp files are littered with `Rcpp::Rcout << thistestobj << std::endl;` statements while I'm developing them.

Comment: Sometimes, when I'm having trouble with `Rcpp`, I try to convert everything to pure `c++` (e.g. something like `NumericVector -->> std::vector<double>`) and use  the debugger in Visual Studio. It is a lot of work, but sometimes, it is just really hard to track down elusive errors with just `print` statements.

Comment: The Rcpp::Rcput << ii << std::endl; works great. I have never been able to get Rcpp to print until now. It is a huge step in debugging.

Comment: Joseph, how would converting to c++ and Visual Studio help? A while ago I was able to set up Eclipse so I could write code in Eclipse, but I still could not debug in it and it eventually became unstable so back to Rstudio. If in my small example I used vector instead of Numeric vector how would I continue? Thank you.

Comment: You can also find a nice step-by-step description here: http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2014-September/008036.html

Comment: @MichaelE The link to [Debugging Rcpp c++ code using gdb](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200655937-Debugging-Rcpp-c-code-using-gdb) seems to be dead or behind a pay wall. Would it be possible for you to add the essential parts to your question? THX :-)

Answer (score 7):

The usual approach `R -d gdb`, which I also suggested in my original answer below, does not work on Windows:

> --debugger=name
>   -d name
>
> (**UNIX only**) Run R through debugger name. For most debuggers (the exceptions are valgrind and recent versions of gdb), further command line options are disregarded, and should instead be given when starting the R executable from inside the debugger.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line

Alternative:

1. Start R in debugger: `gdb.exe Rgui.exe`
2. Set break point: `break TimesTwo2`
3. Run R: `run`
4. Source file: `Rcpp::sourceCpp("debug.cpp")`
5. Use `next`, `print`, `display` to step through the code.

An alternative to step 1. would be to start R, get the PID with `Sys.getpid()`, attach debugger with `gdb -p <pid>`. You will than have to use `continue` instead of `run`.

---

I don't have a Windows machine right now, so the following was done on Linux. I hope it is transferable, though. Let's start with a simple cpp file (`debug.cpp` in my case) that contains your code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using Rcpp::NumericVector;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo2(NumericVector x) {
  for(int ii = 0; ii <= x.size(); ii++)
  {
    x.at(ii) = x.at(ii) * 2;
  }
  return x;
}

/*** R
data = c(1:10)
data
timesTwo2(data)
*/
```

I can reproduce the error by calling R on the command line:

```
$ R -e "Rcpp::sourceCpp('debug.cpp')"

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
[...]

> Rcpp::sourceCpp('debug.cpp')

> data = c(1:10)

> data
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> timesTwo2(data)
Error in timesTwo2(data) : Index out of bounds: [index=10; extent=10].
Calls: <Anonymous> ... source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> timesTwo2 -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Next we can start R with `gdb` as debugger (c.f. *Writing R Extensions* as Dirk said):

```
$ R -d gdb -e "Rcpp::sourceCpp('debug.cpp')"
GNU gdb (Debian 8.2-1) 8.2
[...]
(gdb) break timesTwo2
Function "timesTwo2" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (timesTwo2) pending.
(gdb) run
[...]
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('debug.cpp')
[Thread 0xb40d3b40 (LWP 31793) exited]
[Detaching after fork from child process 31795]

> data = c(1:10)

> data
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> timesTwo2(data)

Thread 1 "R" hit Breakpoint 1, 0xb34f3310 in timesTwo2(Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>)@plt ()
   from /tmp/RtmphgrjLg/sourceCpp-i686-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.0/sourcecpp_7c2d7f56744b/sourceCpp_2.so
(gdb)
```

At this point you can single step through the program using `next` (or just `n`) and output variables using `print` (or just `p`). A useful command is also `display`:

```
Thread 1 "R" hit Breakpoint 1, timesTwo2 (x=...) at debug.cpp:5
5   NumericVector timesTwo2(NumericVector x) {
(gdb) n
6     for(int ii = 0; ii <= x.size(); ii++)
(gdb) n
8       x.at(ii) = x.at(ii) * 2;
(gdb) display ii
2: ii = 0
(gdb) n
8       x.at(ii) = x.at(ii) * 2;
2: ii = 0

[...]

2: ii = 9
(gdb) 
46          inline proxy ref(R_xlen_t i) { return start[i] ; }
2: ii = 9
(gdb) 
6     for(int ii = 0; ii <= x.size(); ii++)
2: ii = 10
(gdb) 
8       x.at(ii) = x.at(ii) * 2;
2: ii = 10
(gdb) 
Error in timesTwo2(data) : Index out of bounds: [index=10; extent=10].
Calls: <Anonymous> ... source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> timesTwo2 -> .Call
Execution halted
[Detaching after fork from child process 32698]
[Inferior 1 (process 32654) exited with code 01]
```

BTW, I used the following compile flags:

```
$ R CMD config CXXFLAGS
-g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
```

You might want to switch to `-O0`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this only works for linux. When I have a chance I will try setting up linux box and then follow your example. If it works I might start debugging in linux when needed.

Comment: @MichaelE What result do you get on Windows?

Comment: I can run the code in cmd directly with Rtools installed. It first says ARGUMENT 'gdb'  __ignored__ and then it continues to run the code and give the same error as before. So it seems gdb works differently in windows.

Comment: @MichaelE Interesting. See the updated answer for an alternative (still untested).

Comment: I did the break TimesTwo2 exactly as you suggested. It said: No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command. Make breakepoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) Breakepoint 1 (TimesTwo2) pending.  When I run it runs rgui just as before and still results with the same error and no breaks. Thanks.

Comment: I finally set up Ubuntu and executed exactly as you did and I got the same result with the line, but not much more error details. This can't be the best there is? The sample is only 10 lines, how do I reasonably go thorough thousands or millions of lines? Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelE the above commands where meant to get you started. See the [gdb documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) for things like conditional breakpoints etc.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with Visual Studio Code, since it can handle both `R` and `C++`. This allows you to step through your `Rcpp` code one line at a time in a GUI environment.

See this [demo](https://github.com/renkun-ken/vscode-rcpp-demo) to get started.

Comment: Thanks, is there a specific version I need? I have 2012 Pro which did not work for me, but it has been a while. Can I use mine or do I have to upgrade? Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelE I'm not familiar with "2012 Pro". I just started using VS Code for this particular problem, and my software says Version: 1.43.1. I am on Ubuntu (Linux) btw, but it should work on Windows. Note this is VS *Code*, and not the MS Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: I did not realize that. I thought VS Code was just a newer version MS Visual Studio. Thanks, I will try it and update if I get it working. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelE did you get **any** of the methods to work? I have gotten as far, as succesfully activating the debugger using the tiny example in "Writing R Extensions" (not in a Dll), and I can get VS code working on standard c++ code but not dll's executed through R. Even changing makeconf/makevars/makevars.win removing -DNDEBUG and adding -g does not seem to do much.

Comment: It's been a while but yes, I do believe I got the demo to successfully debug.

Comment: Worked like a charm today.